# How to fill ember.js models from server response in json format?

Tags: ember.js

I have a list on **emberjs**. I want to create a new elements of that list with data from server. The data are transmitted via ajax in json format and looks like this:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "material": 
  [
    {
      "user1": "test",
      "create_datetime": "2013-03-30 10:36:24+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to fill `ember.js` models of my list?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by iterating over your returned material data. (coffeescript)

Models

```
App.Material = Ember.Object.extend
  userId: null
  createDateTime: null

App.Item = Ember.Object.extend
  status: null
  materials: []
```

Controller

```
App.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend

  init: ->
    @loadData()

  loadData: =>
    $.ajax
      url: "/api/items"
      success: (data) =>
        if data?    
          # create an item object
          item = App.Item.create
                   status: data.status

          # loop through all materials for current item
          for material in data.material
            # push materials onto item.material stack
            item.materials.pushObject App.Material.create
                                        userId: material.user1
                                        createDateTime: material.create_datetime

          # set the controllers content to the item
          @set('content') item
```